# JPEG footer read

Tags: jpeg, footer

Does a JPeg image have a footer section?

If so how do I read it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](http://netghost.narod.ru/gff/graphics/summary/jfif.htm) there's a header; no footer!